# How to change Base Image from satellite view in Android Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

Is possible to use different Base Image to show satellite view from  RapidEye satellites using Goggle Maps API? I have no problems with Google images but I am looking for new geospacial image fonts. I just want to put a different "background" in satellite view mode from online database.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question properly. This might get tricky. But did you check this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes

Comment: I didn't know how to ask, now i know that what I was looking for was change WMS Server, but thank you so much :)